# css - element color to the browser specific placeholder color

Tags: css, colors, cross-browser, placeholder

I have a custom element which I want to have a font color which is the same as the default input placeholder color (which varies by browser/OS).
Is there any css way to set the color to be dynamic according to the current browser's default?
Thanks

Comment: If i was not wrong you trying to set input placeholder color different for different browsers?

Comment: `-webkit-focus-ring-color` is an example of system dependent color.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly get the placeholder color, but you can override them:

```css
:root {
  --placeholder-color: salmon;
}

*::placeholder {
  color: var(--placeholder-color);
}

.test {
  color: var(--placeholder-color);
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Input something..." value="" />
<div class="test">Placeholder Color</div>
```

Or you can use the `input` tag instead, and set the `placeholder` accordingly.
Then set its `all: unset` to make it looks like a normal div:

```css
.test {
  all: unset;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Input something..." value="" />
<input class="test" disabled="disabled" placeholder="Placeholder Color" />
```